# Laptop Lenovo T15p Gen 2 with Ubuntu 22.04 LTS consumes battery very fast

Tags: power-management, lenovo, battery, 22.04

I just got a new laptop Lenovo T15p Gen 2 and remove the Windows 10 and installed Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. The problem is that the battery gets drained very fast. I installed the last bios version and check the parameters on it. Not much to choose for. It there any trick to make the battery last longer? I checked other questions in askubuntu but they are for older versions of Ubuntu.
Thank you.

Comment: The Lenovo T15p has hybrid graphics (Intel+Nvidia). In Windows it always uses the iGPU (Intel) for everything except high demanding software that when started will trigger a seamless transition to the dGPU (on-demand) and that alone accounts for the extended battery life you're comparing with. In Ubuntu you should assure the proper Nvidia drivers are installed and then use Nvidia X Server Settings to select profiles. Choose Intel and reboot. Change again to Nvidia (high-performance) whenever needed and only when needed (games, 3D rendering and similar).

Comment: @ChanganAuto - I think this is a good answer (certainly better than the answer below!). Maybe change to an answer?

Answer (score 0):

The Lenovo T15p has hybrid graphics (Intel+Nvidia). In Windows it always uses the iGPU (Intel) for everything except high demanding software that when started will trigger a seamless transition to the dGPU (on-demand) and that alone accounts for the extended battery life you're comparing with.

In Ubuntu you should assure the proper Nvidia drivers are installed and then use Nvidia X Server Settings to select profiles. Choose Intel and reboot. Change again to Nvidia (high-performance) whenever needed and only when needed (games, 3D rendering and similar).

Comment: In Lenovo there isn't any drivers for Nvidia for Ubuntu. Only for Windows.

Comment: In Software And Updates, appears Nvidia Corporation: TU117M and it is using X.org X server. The other options are driver 510, 450, 470,510-server,450-server,470-server. This computer has the NVIDIA® GeForce® GTX 1650 and Intel integrated UHD.

Comment: Open Additional Drivers (or Software & Updates > Additional Drivers tab), select and apply the recommended drivers version and reboot, **as always**. Of course manufacturers that don't officially support other OSes NEVER publish drivers for said OSes, Nvidia's or any others. **Also disable Secure Boot in UEFI in order to use the Nvidia drivers.** This is very basic stuff you need to understand.

Comment: And for future reference: When installing Ubuntu make sure to select the option to install 3rd party drivers, firmware, codecs, etc. so it's done automatically.

Comment: I installed the Ubuntu with the 3rd party drivers checked.

Comment: Are you sure? *In Software And Updates, appears (...) and it is using X.org X server* says you didn't, otherwise the latest version of the proprietary drivers would be the one in use. AGAIN, **disable Secure Boot in UEFI**. Once properly installed please try what I mentioned in the answer and check for yourself the improved battery life. After that please accept the answer, this is how the site works.

Comment: I have a version of  Lenovo T15p Gen 2  with only one video card (Integrated Intel UHD Graphics) and it's also hot like hell and drying battery extremely fast. If I have several VS Code windows opened and/or lots of tabs in Chrome - tempretare bumps up to 100C and battery lives for 1.5-2 hours.
Have the last available drives from the official Lenovo site installed. Ubuntu 22.04.1.
Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score -1):

Since your laptop is Thinkpad, i would suggest TLP ( noted that you need to Uninstall the conflicting power-profiles-daemon package).

Comment: No, don't. It won't make any significant difference. Look for my comment under the answer to understand what's happening.

Comment: that's strange since tlp gives you lots of options for thinkpad, for example charge threshold, battery recalibration,

Comment: And any of those options - assuming they do anything significant (they don't and in some cases make it worse) - are moot if the user has the Nvidia card running 100% of the time and on top of that using the not-so-good alternative open-source driver like we discovered in comments. Again, read my answer .